# how to use a control name in Class.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below is the class code having different control names.
The error is

> The name 'control_name' does not exist in the current context for
>   every control name.

Note: The html controls have `runat=server`-property along them.

```
namespace Wcd_Web_Dashboard.Classes
{
    public class ClassA
    {
        public static void clear(string m_name)
        {
            if (m_name == "Register")
            {
                txt_Username.Value = string.Empty;
                txt_user.Value = string.Empty;
                txt_comment.Value = string.Empty;
                ddl_district.SelectedIndex = 0;
                ddl_tehsils.SelectedIndex = 0;
                txt_FromDate.Value = string.Empty;
                txt_ToDate.Value = string.Empty;
                txt_RUserName.Value = string.Empty;
                txt_RPassword.Value = string.Empty;
                txt_RRePassword.Value = string.Empty;
            }
            if (m_name == "Login")
            {
                txt_Username.Value = string.Empty;
                txt_Pass.Value = string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can´t even see any `control_name` in your code.

Comment: A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be really awsome.

Answer (score 0):

Your "current context" is that the method is static. And thus none of the controls exist (because those are instance level controls, not static level). Remove the `static` modifier from the method and your errors will go away.